# Unity - WaitForSeconds Not Working Inside Update or a Loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to instantiate an object continuously. To do this, I need to have some sort of interval or wait timer so it doesn't instantiate everything at once. I came up with this:

```
public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
     public GameObject Enemy;

     public void Update()
     {
          var random = new Random();
          var randomX = random.Next(-12, 12);
          var randomY = random.Next(-5, 5); 
          StartCoroutine(Spawn(randomX, randomY));
     }

     public IEnumerator Spawn(int randomX, int randomY)
     {
          yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
          Instantiate(Enemy, new Vector3(randomX, randomY), Quaternion.identity);
     }
}
```

What ends up happening is that it will wait for 3 seconds (as coded) and then instantiate as many objects as it can at once. The result I was hoping for was that it would spawn one, wait three seconds, spawn another one etc... Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Update runs every frame. If your previous frame's update is still running, it doesn't matter. It will run it anyway. Don't do this in your update. Every frame you are starting a new coroutine by doing this. If you get 100 frames per second, you are starting 100 coroutines per second. You need to put some conditions on it to stop this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Josh already commented, you start a new coroutine everytime your update method runs.

To fix this, you can:

either start your coroutine somewhere else (in the `start()` method if it should run from the beginning)

```
public void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(Spawn(randomX, randomY));
}
```

or if the coroutine needs to be called by your update for whatever reason, you can use something like this:

```
private bool spawnCoroutineStarted = false;

public void Update() {
    // other code
    if (!spawnCoroutineStarted) {
        spawnCoroutineStarted = true;
        StartCoroutine(Spawn(randomX, randomY));
    }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to Draco18s, for pointing out my oversight.

To spawn enemies continuously you could change the `Spawn` method like this:

```
public IEnumerator Spawn(randomX, randomY) {
    while (true) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        Instantiate(Enemy, new Vector3(randomX, randomY), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, that if you want to use `StopCoroutine` later on you have to store the IEnumerator returned by `Spawn` and use the `StopCoroutine` method on that reference.

Also, if you really want to have something reoccuring over a specific time frame you might want to consider using [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html?_ga=2.192050218.1631235265.1575888531-1765729503.1561463521) instead of coroutines.

Comment: Note that both of these will only spawn 1 enemy as the coroutine in the question is not a loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to continually spawn, you could use a touch of recursion.

```
void Start()
{        
    StartCoroutine(Spawn());
}

public IEnumerator Spawn()
 {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    var random = new Random();
    var randomX = random.Next(-12, 12);
    var randomY = random.Next(-5, 5); 
    Instantiate(Enemy, new Vector3(randomX, randomY), Quaternion.identity);
    StartCoroutine(Spawn());
 }
```